# How to optimize my code with useMemo in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I have a situation in React with the `useMemo()` hook.

I have an array object called `a`. This object contains multiple objects. This array is large. When it contains `b` and `c` objects, `a` looks like `a = [b,c]`. I am doing heavy computation on array `a`. Here is my code snippet:

```
    const computedValue = useMemo(() => {
         return a.map(key,() => {
           anotherHighComputationFunc(key);
         });
    },[a])

const anotherHighComputationFunc = useMemo((key) => {
        // ..... do some expensive computation
       return someValue;
},[key]);
```

If a reference of `a` does not change, I do not compute the value again, I just return the precomputed value. If a reference of `a` changes then I will look into the array `a` to check if some key has changed its reference inside the array. If for some key reference has not changed then return the precomputed value for that key, otherwise do computation for that key.

The issue is that the rule of hook fails as I am using a hook inside another hook. So it throws me an error. Is there any other way round to do memoization at 2 levels?

Comment: Hooks can be used in other hooks, but I suspect the issue is with *some* "conditional" hook invocation, though I don't see from your snippet where a hook is called inside another hook. Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: @DrewReese I believe the issue is calling the useMemo inside map function which is a loop and React asks to avoid using hooks inside loops.

Comment: Perhaps, it's either considered being invoked in a loop (but you are calling the memozied callback) or from a nested function (I think it is this one). Sounds like you can just roll your own simple cache.

Answer (score 1):

The `useMemo()` hook won't help you here, because it has a cache size of 1, and you can't call hooks inside other hooks. In addition, you don't need to memoize the function, but the results of the call.

You can create a simple memoization wrapper using [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) that will allow the garbage collector to clean the values when not needed.

Note: WeakMap keys must be objects.

```
const weakMemo = fn => {
  const map = new WeakMap();
  
  return obj => {
    if (map.has(obj)) return map.get(obj);
    
    const res = fn(obj);
    
    map.set(obj, res);
    
    return rs;
  }
};

// the useMemo is needed here to preserve the instance of the memoized function with the cached values
const computeKey = useMemo(() => weakMemo((key) => {
  // ..... do some expensive computation
  return someValue;
}), [anotherHighComputationFunc]);

const computedValue = useMemo(() => a.map(computeKey), [a, computeKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules of Hooks clearly state: Don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.

Rather than using a hook for your `anotherHighComputationFunc`, create a `cache` object which stores the values of the function and return it if it is inside the cache object.

```
const cache = {};

function anotherHighComputationFunc(key) {
   if (cache[key]) return cache[key];

    /** anotherHighComputation calculation here */
    cache[key] = anotherHighComputationValue;
    return anotherHighComputationValue
} 

 const computedValue = useMemo(() => {
     return a.map(key,() => {
       anotherHighComputationFunc(key);
    });
},[a])
```

Comment: This is the best way. But the problem here is I have to maintain my own cache which may not be as efficient as useMemo is. If there other way where I can avoid creating my own cache and use some best already implemented memorization techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by `my own cache which may not be as efficient as useMemo is`? Object lookup has `O(1)` time complexity. Could you elaborate what does `more efficient` mean here?

Comment: By efficient I mean , there has to some regular memory cleanups so that my memory is not mostly occupied by cache object. As React has also mentioned on its website for useMemo:  `In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components`.

Comment: @unpredictable Make sense, then just `useRef` to collect values and use it as a cache. I've updated the code above.

Comment: The so called 'rule', stating `Don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.`, is not being violated anyway. `anotherHighComputationFunc` is not a hook, it is a value returned by a hook, to which the 'rule' does not apply.

Comment: So I think that the first solution of @PrateekThapa seems good! Don't use the second because of some violated rules like said above. And for cleaning up cache object onUnmount of Component, useEffect will be able to resolve. I hope so!